# Can you give an example for theorem following?

Tags: analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $f:E\rightarrow (-\infty ,\infty]$ be a proper closed function and assume that $C$ is a compact set satisfying $ C \cap dom(f)≠ \emptyset$. then

1) $f$ is bounded below over C

2) $f$ attains its minimal value over C

Can you give an example for this theorem?

thaks.

Comment: What's a"closed function"? What is $dom(f)$, if not $(-\infty,\infty]$?

Comment: @amsmath, $E$ is finite dimensional  and a function is closed if its epigraph is closed.

Comment: You just want an example? Well, $f=0$ does it.

Comment: @amsmath, what is compact set $C$?

Comment: It doesn't matter, but if you want so: $E = \mathbb R$, $C = [0,1]$.

Comment: I would suggest $E = \{0\} = \mathbb R^0$, $f(0) = 0$ and $C = E$.

Comment: @grew, thanks grew. Is this an example for the coercive function, with the exception that set C is replaced by a nonempty closed set?